# Get a clean message from json array

Tags: node.js

`

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')                                                                                                                                                                     
const db = require('quick.db')                                                                                                                                                                            
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {                                                                                                                                                                

let pointiz = JSON.stringify(db.all(10))                                                                                                                                                                  
message.channel.send(pointiz)                                                                                                                                                                             


}                                                                                                                                                                                                         

exports.conf = {                                                                                                                                                                                          
  enabled: true,                                                                                                                                                                                          
  guildOnly: false,                                                                                                                                                                                       
  aliases: ["stats"],                                                                                                                                                                                     
  permLevel: 1                                                                                                                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                                                                                        

exports.help = {                                                                                                                                                                                          
  name: 'lead',                                                                                                                                                                                           
  description: 'Text.',                                                                                                                                                               
  usage: 'text'                                                                                                                                                                                       
};    `
```

What im trying to do is to get a clean message into a leaderboard buy i dont know how to translate these strings.

Message:

`[{"ID":"Usur","data":{"points":200}},{"ID":"points","data":0},{"ID":"Usur-427258453501673484","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"Usur427258453501673484","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"Usur-484607136345751564","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"427258453501673484","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"Usur-198504055885004800","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"198504055885004800","data":{"points":10}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, take a look @ this example:

```js
let results = [{"ID":"Usur","data":{"points":200}},{"ID":"points","data":0},{"ID":"Usur-427258453501673484","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"Usur427258453501673484","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"Usur-484607136345751564","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"427258453501673484","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"Usur-198504055885004800","data":{"points":0}},{"ID":"198504055885004800","data":{"points":10}}];

// PRINT HOW YOU WISH INSIDE THE forEach LOOP
results.forEach( x => console.log( x ) );
```

Comment: Got a nice result but my main idea is to get a clean message for each of them as u correctly said but with this format | MentionedUser : Points |

Comment: then just interpolate values in a string, accessing them with `x.id`, `x.data', ..

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you got is clearly an array of objects. To access its elements you'd wanna do something like `pointiz[ i ].field`.... Obviously, not JSON.stringifying it. Question is far too broad btw.

Comment: The thing is that if i parse it i got [object Object] as a response

Comment: What you got is a raw JSON response, ok? Now you can parse it into an object, or stringify it. Of course printing an object makes no sense, but also stringifying it won't give you pretty formatted output, of course. What you wanna do is cycle through the array, if what you wanna do is print the answer in a humanly-readable way. But of course, "get[ting] a clean message into a leaderboard" is not accurate enough for me to decipher what your main goal is here.

Comment: Oh, i want it to look like this | MentionedUser  ( <@ + userID + > ) : points (numbers) | all that sorted i think sort()